# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object nextjs

Tags: javascript, object, next.js

what could be causing this error in y nextjs code

```js
export default function SignIn({ providers }: any) {
    return (
        <>
            {Object.values(providers).map((provider: any) => (
                <Center key={provider.name} sx={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }}>
                    <Stack spacing='xl'>
                        <Title align='center'>Welcome to Inventory App</Title>
                        {provider.name === "Google" && (
                            <Button onClick={() => signIn(provider.id)} size='lg' sx={{ alignSelf:'center' }}>
                                <Group>
                                    <Text size='md'>Sign in With {provider.name}</Text>
                                    <FaGoogle/>
                                </Group>
                            </Button>
                        )}
                    </Stack>
                </Center>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately to make it readable.

Comment: One possible cause could be Object.values(providers) . You are trying to access providers even before the values are populated.

It would be helpful if you can share how are you using SignIn component.